# How to match values of a dataframe with another dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df1 and df2 (attached image). I want to create three new columns in df1 (value1,value2,value3) and input the values accordingly (result as in df3) The data are quite large so I need a pythonic way of doing this.

I have tried a few ways in Pandas to stack and merge but I can't debug the issues because there are 3 different value columns to merge.

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work with a list:

```
list = ['value1','value2','value3']
df1= pd.merge(df1, df2, on=list1, how='left')
```

[image]

Comment: df1.merge(df2) ?

Comment: Never mind. I just figured it out. Thanks!